# Select all rows where columns have all values in a list

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

Sorry for the lack of a better question title, I'll change it if someone knows the SQL jargon of what I'm trying to do to make it Google-able.

I have the following table from a hospital.

```
 subject_id | hadm_id | icd9_code 
------------+---------+-----------
          3 |  145834 | 5849
          3 |  145834 | 4280
          9 |  150750 | 5849
          9 |  150750 | 4019
          9 |  150750 | 4280
         12 |  112213 | 4019
         13 |  143045 | 4019
         13 |  143045 | 25000
         13 |  143045 | 41401
         17 |  161087 | 2724
         17 |  194023 | 2724
```

where `subject_id` is unique to a patient and `hadm_id` is unique to a patient admission to the hospital (a hospital stay). Each `icd9_code` represents a disease. So, for example, patient number 3 has been diagnosed with two diseases (5849 and 4280) in their only hospital stay.

I'm given a list of disease codes and I need to return the list of patients that have been diagnosed with at least **all** of those diseases.

Note that diagnoses may be repeated for the same patient (in the example, patient 17 has been diagnosed with disease 2724 twice on two different hospital stays).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Postgres' array handling for this:

```
select subject_id
from the_table
group by subject_id
having array_agg(distinct icd9_code) @> array[4280, 5849];
```

`array_agg()` collects all codes for each subject_id and the operator `@>` checks if that array contains all elements from the other expression.

Comment: I don't use much Postgres. I didn't realize it had real array handling. That is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the patients with the given disease list and check if the distinct count of disease match with the provided list count per stay:

```
select subject_id, hadm_id 
from your_table
where icd9_code in (5849, 5850, 5851)
group by subject_id, hadm_id 
having count(distinct icd9_code) = 3;
```